# Windows 10 IoT Core How to leave On Screen Keyboard

Tags: xaml, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, windows-iot-core-10

I installed version v.10.0.17661.1001 of Windows 10 IoT Core on a Raspberry PI 3 with a 7" Touchscreen Display.

I setup the device to have *"Show the on-screen keyboard when text input controls have focus"*

When I enter an input control, for example into the built in Navigator, the keyboard appears, I can use it to enter a new URL. When I touch the "enter" key, the Navigator show the content of the new URL, but the keyboard stays on the screen and it keeps the focus. I'am not able to use the Navigator nor anything else.

[image]

- I can touch anywhere in the red part, but nothing happens.
- When I touch a key in the green part, it appears in the TextBox of the browser. When I touch enter the browser navigate to the new URL and a combo-box appears with some other URLs.

**How can I remove the On Screen Keyboard and above all continue to use the interface ?**

I've got the same behaviour with my own UWP code.

Did I miss Something ?

---

The Windows Update is Greyed :

[image]

Comment: Do you try to focus on other element? like a button...

Comment: Yes, The on-screen keyboard keep the focus.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue on version 10.0.17686.1003. It seems all screen freeze except the TextBox of the browser. You can submit this issue via [feedback hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/).

Comment: Ijust do it on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a790430a-28fd-478c-b9d4-ad051170060e/windows-iot-core-how-to-leave-on-screen-keyboard?forum=WindowsIoT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest insider preview version 10.0.17744.1001 don't have this issue. If you use Raspberry Pi 3B(not 3B+, because 3B+ only can run 17661 currently) you can use the version 10.0.17744.1001.

And another workaround is using a hardware keyboard instead of on-screen keyboard. It works.

Comment: Thanks  for this test, I'am going to have a look. The SSDis no longer easily accessible, and  the update button is greyed, Do you know if there is a software way to update my box ?

Comment: @JPBlanc Are you talking about "Check for updates" button in the device portal? AFAIK, when it is downloading the update the button is not able to click otherwise it is able to click to check the update. And have you ever disabled the system update?

Comment: Yes the "Check for updates" button in the device portal is greyed. I do not disable the update system. I try to stop and start again the update service, it does nothing still greyed.

Comment: @JPBlanc Can you share a snapshot of the greyed update button?

Comment: @JPBlanc Thanks for your update. It is doing the download(Downloading updates) so the greyed button is expected. If it always hangs here you can reboot the device and check again. And one more thing I need confrim with you, is your board [Raspberry Pi 3B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/)?

Comment: I reboot multiple times, and it's still greyed, it's an old RASPBERRY PI 3 MODEL.

Comment: @JPBlanc Thanks for the information. I am contacting with the related engineer of this issue and update to you if there is any progress.

Comment: I install 10.0.17744.1001, but I met some problems with On Screen Keyboard (screen completly frozen). I'll have a look tonight.